# How to remove '&'-words encoding from libxml2?

Tags: c, libxml2

I have an XML file which should be parsed and processed. For that reason I'm using `libxml2`.

The xml file I have looks something like this:

*test.xml*

```xml
<root>
     <tag attr1="VALUE_1 &quot;" attr2="VALUE_2 &#xA; VALUE_3" />
</root>
```

And I want to get the attribute contents. BUT the libxml2 seems to encode the '&'-words (don't know how to call them).

The code I use is the following one:

```c
LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

xmlDoc *doc;
doc = xmlReadFile("test.xml", NULL, XML_PARSE_IGNORE_ENC);

xmlNode *root;
root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

xmlNode *node;
node = root->children;

while (node != NULL) {
        if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {

                xmlAttr *attr;
                attr = node->properties;

                while (attr != NULL) {
                        xmlNode *child;
                        child = attr->children;

                        while (child != NULL) {
                                if (child->type == XML_TEXT_NODE || 
                                    child->type == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) 
                                        printf("%s\n", child->content);

                                child = child->next;
                        }

                        attr = attr->next;
                }
        }       

        node = node->next;
}
```

So basically I want to print the attribute values, BUT they are being parsed with a formatting (I guess). When I run this code than I see following output:

```
VALUE_1 "

VALUE_2 
 VALUE_3
```

As you can see it translated the '&'-words. How can I hint the libxml2 to not do that and give me the literal text values.

Comment: @KamilCuk didn't work.

Comment: did you try xmlSubstituteEntitiesDefault(0) ? the name for this data is entities

Comment: The "& words" are called XML entities. And you cannot tell libxml2 to not decode them, as that functionality is deeply engrained in its code. Have a look at `parser.c` in the libxml2 source, specifically `xmlParseAttValueInternal`/`xmlParseAttValueComplex`.

Comment: @PtitXav it didn't work.

Comment: @Siguza do you know an alternative library which can ignore XML entities (preferably it is available in `vcpkg`)? Or at least can I keep track of those XML entities so later I can print out a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't. libxml2 will always decode numeric character references like `&#xA;` and predefined entities like `&quot;`. But `&#65;` and `A`, for example, are semantically equivalent. If you really need to tell them apart, you're probably doing something wrong elsewhere in your XML pipeline. If you want a literal `&#xA;` in an attribute value, you have to encode it as `&amp;#xA;`.

Note that the expansion can be controlled for other, user-defined entities via the `XML_PARSE_NOENT` parser flag, but this won't affect numeric character references.